# I have permission to the table, but not to a view that uses the table

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I am having a behaviour I cannot understand, and I have no idea where to look for solutions.

I have a view called `wms_view_orderline` that gets information from the `wms_orderline` table. When I `SELECT` from the `wms_orderline` table, I get information. But when I use the view, I get this error:

```
bf=# select * from wms_view_orderline ;
ERROR:  permission denied for table wms_orderline
```

My user is superuser (even `postgres` gets this error), and has all permissions on the table and view granted.

**Update** when I recreated the exact same view with another name, it works.

Comment: Is the other view created under a different account? Does it have the same schema owner as the tables? That might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select from a view, it runs as the user who created the view.  Apparently this view was created by a user who did not have access (or later lost access) to the underlying table.

Why would someone do that?  No idea.  The permissions system is flexible and let you do all sorts of wonderful things, but also all sorts of nonsense.